# Get index count from the JS array in group

Tags: javascript, math

I have declared a total of 5 array items.
I grouped it in groups of 3 or n and got a total count.
I wrote this code.

```
const list = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bar'
   },
   {
    id: 3,
    name: 'fubar'
   },
   {
    id: 4,
    name: 'barz'
   },
   {
    id: 5,
    name: 'foobar'
   }
]
const itemCounts = list.length
const page = 3 or n
const totalPage = Math.ceil(itemCounts / page)
```

I suppose I was grouped like this.

```
[ 'foo' ][ 'bar' ][ 'fubar'] -- group1
[ 'barz'][ 'foobar']         -- group2
```

This is the total count of the group.

```
console.log('totalGroupPage', totalPage)

//output
2
```

I have a question.
For example, I have index 2, which is the second item `{ id: 3, name: 'fubar' }`.

I'd like to know the number of the group this item belongs to.

```
// example
getGroupIndex(2) // list[2]

// I wanna group number
1


getGroupIndex(3) // list[3]

// I wanna group number
2
```

How can you implement the `getGroupIndex()` function?

Comment: show the group json

Comment: You can try to use ```const getGroupIndex = (i) => {
 const groupPage = Math.floor(i / page);
 return groupPage + 1;
};```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the group number by dividing the index by the amount of elements you want per `page`. You can then floor this, and add 1 (as you group numbers start from 1 and not 0):

```
group = Math.floor(idx / page) + 1;
```

See example below:

```js
const list = [
  { id: 1, name: 'foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'bar' }, { id: 3, name: 'fubar' }, 
  { id: 4, name: 'barz' }, { id: 5, name: 'foobar' }
];
const page = 3;

const getGroupNumber = idx  => Math.floor(idx / page) + 1;

list.forEach((_, i) => console.log(getGroupNumber(i)));
```